# Vue2-leaflet use ES modules to decrease bundle size

Tags: vue.js, webpack, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I'm using Vue-cli 2 and import Vue2-leaflet modules `LMap`, `LTileLayer` in my main.js with

```
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from 'vue2-leaflet'
```

By using webpack-bundle-analyzer I can see the bundle size is still 421kb (leaflet-src.js only).

**Why is this not decreased significantly, as the docs state;**

> Is highly suggested to import only the needed modules by doing so:
> `import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker } from 'vue2-leaflet';`
> This will reduce the size of the bundle significantly

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at this same problem. I don't think importing the individual vue2-leaflet components will have any affect on the leaflet-src.js import, which as you stated is over 400kb. It will, however, reduce the vue2-leaflet components. If you load all of the vue2-leaflet components, it will about 242kb (unzipped). This can be reduced significantly with the method you are using.

I would certainly appreciate if leaflet made it possible not to have to use their entire bundle, but I don't believe that's possible.